# Layout not rendering in layout.xml

Tags: php, xml, magento

I have created a custom module and called my layout.xml file in config.xml

This is the code of my layout.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<layout version="0.1.0">   
  <cartpdf_index_index>   
    <reference name="root">   
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>   
    </reference>   
    <reference name="content">   
      <block type="cartpdf/index" name="cartpdf_index" template="cartpdf/index.phtml"/>   
    </reference>   
  </cartpdf_index_index>  
</layout>
```

When I check cartpdf index controller using `die()` it works even it sets the layout of the page 1column, 2columns-left whatever you set. but it doesn't call phtml file in content area.

I checked this module in my local system in fresh Magento and its working fine there but not in server.

What could be possible problem for that?

Comment: check if you have correct block type, by instantiating it in demo file

Comment: <global>
<blocks>
   <cartpdf>
  <class>Test_Cartpdf_Block</class>
   </cartpdf>
</blocks>
</global>
and it's working where i created it and in my local system. but not in different client server

Comment: If your local and client platform is different, recheck the case of folder's, it might cause the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It was compilation mode on issue. I disabled that and now its working fine.